# How do I Update JTextField text from another panel object

Tags: java, swing

I have 4 panels running on one frame .. each panel has its own class where. each panel class has its own widgets and layout. I'm trying to update panel2's textField from panel1's textField input.

I have tried calling panel2.textfield.setText("what ever text needed"); on panel1's textfield actionEvent the value does changes when I check on system.out.println() method but the swing UI doesn't change unless the two textfields are defined under one constructor which is something I don't want

this is just a concept to have you understand what i wanna do.

```
class1 extends JPanel{
JTextField textfield1;
class1(){
 textfield1 = JTextField();
 add(textfield1);
 textfield1.addActionListener((ActionEvent evt)->{
  change(evt);
  system.out.println(textfield1.getText())
});
}
void change(ActionEvent evt){
  new Class2.textfield2.setText("y");
}
}

class2 extends JPanel{
JTextfield textfield2;
class2(){
 texfield2 = new JTextField("x");
 add(textfield2);
}
}

Mainclass extends JFrame{
Mainclass(){
setOnDef....(JFrame.exit_onclose);
 Class1 class1 = new Class1();
 Class2 class2 = new Class2();

add(class1);
add(class2);
pack();
}

public void main(String[]args){
SwingUtilities.invokelater(()->{
 new Mainclass.setVisible(true);
});
}
}
```

I expect X to change to Y .I have tried everything swingWorker, invokelater, creating a string variable that will hold the text to pass via constructor, nothing but putting everything in one class works seems to work

Comment: The first thing you really, really, want to do, is do some research into something called the "observer pattern", you then want to do some research into something called the "model-view-controller pattern" (which the observer pattern is used in).  This will allow you to define a "model" which can be shared and when updated, will notify all the other interested parties of the change.  This is a really important concept as it de-couples your code and isolates the implementation detail, making your code less fragile

Comment: ok thanks I'll have a look at observer pattern

Comment: *"each panel has its own class"* .. Why? General tips: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! Most IDEs have a keyboard shortcut specifically for formatting code.

Comment: @Andrew ... I'll take note next time .... As to why "each panel has its own class" it seems simpler as I wanted something fast but a bit clean ... I'm not going for perfect code, I just wanted something that works but makes sense when looked at

Comment: *"I'll take note next time"* You can [edit] a question at any time. I'll pay closer attention to your post when you do. *"I wanted something fast but a bit clean"* By extending panels unnecessarily, that code went in the wrong direction!

Comment: So what do you suggest I do without having to go the MVC route ?

Comment: The idea of [mcve] is to allow people to copy and run your code. For me, if you don't make that effort, it implies you loathe the people you are asking for help. For example, what do you expect me to do with this line of the "code" you posted: `setOnDef....(JFrame.exit_onclose);` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in this line:

```
new Class2.textfield2.setText("y");
```

By calling `new Class2()` you create a new instance of `Class2` and afterwards change something in it. The instance of `Class2` in your frame stays the same. To solve this you have to get a reference to the object in your frame, for example by passing it over in the constructor, like this:

In `Class1`

```
Class2 class2;

Class1(Class2 class2) {
  this.class2 = class2;
  // Other constructor stuff
}

void change(...) {
  class2.textfield2.setText("y);
}
```

And in `Mainclass`' constructor

```
Class2 class2 = new Class2();
Class1 class1 = new Class1(class2);
```

This way `change` really changes the `TextField` that is displayed.